# Eloquent: order by max difference?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table `stats` like this:

```
id | post_id | num_yes | num_no
1  | 1       | 2       | 0
2  | 1       | 3       | 3
3  | 1       | 1       | 0
```

How can I order by the difference `num_yes - num_no`? The output should look be `1, 3, 2` (in terms of `id`).

I have this currently:

```
$posts = Post::join('stats', 'stats.id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->where('post_id', 1)
    ->orderByRaw('MAX(stats.num_yes - stats.num_no)', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

But this isn't working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering by `MAX(stats.num_yes - stats.num_no)`, which is going to give you the *maximum* value of the differences between those columns (across all rows).  You really just want to order by the difference between those columns for *each* row:

```
$posts = Post::join('stats', 'stats.id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->where('post_id', 1)
    ->orderByRaw('(stats.num_yes - stats.num_no)', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```